# How should we process if someone wishes to increase/maximize the categorical cross-entropy loss for a certain scenario?

Tags: classification, loss-function, cross-entropy

In one of my projects, I need to maximize the entropy loss in a classification model. How should I write the codebase? I'm compatible with keras, tf and pytorch framework.
Any kind of suggestions and direction will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: simply minimize the standard cross-entropy with the - sign

Comment: Thanks @MarcoCerliani, but could you elaborate?